# how to call class using strings

Tags: java, string, class

hello guys i am wondering how to call a class using string item for example

```
class A {
    String[] des = { "hi" };
}

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] className = { "A", "B" };
        System.out.println(className.des[0]); // i wanted to call des array in
                                              // a class with index equal to 0
    }
}
```

from above you can interpret that i wanted a string content to be used as class caller at run time. Is it possible..(i am bound to use String for it)

Comment: Use reflection, although it's not obvious that that's what you're looking for. And you might need to review Java syntax before you proceed.

Comment: can u tell me using code please

Comment: dont edit, if dont get the qus..please i wanted to dynamically give the name if i already know it is class "A" why i will be using this..approach..huh

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense, because `des` is not a field of the `String` array `className`. However, it looks like you're trying to access a field declared in class `A` based on just having the name of the class as a `String` value. Since `des` is an instance field, you need an instance of `A` to work with. You can do something like this:

```
A a = (A) (Class.forName("A").newInstance());
System.out.println(a.des[0]);
```

You'll have to add code to deal with the potential exceptions that this can throw. Also note that the argument to `Class.forName` needs to be the full name of the class, so if `A` is part of a package (say `com.example`), then it would have to be `Class.forName("com.example.A")`.

Here's how to combine Sotirios Delimanolis's and my code into a complete working example:

```
class Example {
    static class A {
        String[] des = { "Hi from class A" };
    }

    static class B {
        String[] des = { "Hi from Class B" };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] classNames = { "Example$A", "Example$B" }; // inner class names
        for (String name : classNames) {
            try {
                System.out.println(getDes0(name));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Could not get des[0] for class " + name);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getDes0(String className)
        throws Exception // better to be explicit, but distracts from the answer
    {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
        Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("des");
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        String[] des = (String[]) field.get(obj);
        return des[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is for calling class dynamically, as you suggest in this, still i have to call specifying class name as "A", so doesnt make sense, so i wanted to parse the des using only the string name as my class name...

Comment: @user2829506 If you don't know the class name, how can you expect to know the field name or how to use it as a `String[]`?

Comment: and for more information des is in different class which i am trying to call dynamically....

Comment: ok its like three class with same code but different name for example three classes are "Cat""dog""Rat" and all of them are having same array --run[]-- So i know run is there in each class but i wanted to use String to access them one by one using loop ,so my array String[] className ={"Dog,"Rat","Cat"}; is there So i wanted to access run[k] in each so an imaginary command can be like className[0].run[0] to access class dog and index 0 of run array...Thanks

Comment: @user2829506 - Ah. In that case, you'll probably need to use the reflection API to access the field. I think [the answer by Sotirios Delimanolis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19188473/535871) shows how to do that (except you can use `clazz.getInstance()` to get the instance instead of `new A()`).

Answer (score 0):

[Use Ted Hopp's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188405/438154)

I'm going to regret showing this to you, but just for kicks

```
String className = "A"; // use the fully qualified name
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("des");
field.setAccessible(true);
A a = new A(); // if you don't know the actual type, you can declare it as Object and get it from somewhere
String[] des = (String[])field.get(a);
System.out.println(des[0]);
```

Obviously do all the exception handling accordingly.

Comment: You can use `Object a = clazz.getInstance()` to get an instance instead of `A a = new A()`. No need for the code to depend on the actual class (which, according to OP, will vary).

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah, after the comment on your answer, the actual object can come from some external source. I've added as a comment in the code snippet. Thanks.